# lowercase breadcrumbs

Tags: case

How do I parse the breadcrumbs code:

```
{% if entry.level > 1 %}
    <ul class="crumbs">
        {% for crumb in entry.getAncestors() %}
            <li>{{ crumb.getLink() }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

into lowercase?

```
Home > blog > entry title
```

or

```
  home > blog > entry title
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with CSS, or with Twig.

CSS:

```
ul.crumbs li {
  text-transform: lowercase;
}
```

…or, if you need to start *after* a particular index…

```
ul.crumbs li:nth-child(n + 2) { /* Start with the 2nd `li` */
  text-transform: lowercase;
}
```

Twig:

```
{% if entry.level > 1 %}
  <ul class="crumbs">
    {% for crumb in entry.getAncestors() %}
      {# Build the link yourself, passing just the title through the `lower` filter: #}
      <li><a href="{{ crumb.url }}">{{ crumb.title | lower }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Brilliant August, I was looking for the Twig function!